# Boolean GetParameterAsText in a loop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, loop, parameters, boolean

I have this tool where the user inputs an ID number and the tool selects a list of features applies symbology (.lyr) and adds the queried features to the open mxd.

```
# Import modules
import arcpy
import os

# Set overwrite option
from arcpy import env
env.overwriteOutput = True

# Set variables
pws = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
files = ["SERVICE_AREA_COMBO", "BACTI", "DBP", "DBP_STAGE2", "OFFICE", "PRV", "PUMP_STATION", "TANK", "VALVE_MISCELLANEOUS", "WTP"]  # list all names used for feature classes and .lyr files.
layers = ["Service Area " + pws, "Bacti " + pws, "DBP " + pws, "DBP Stage 2 " + pws, "Office " + pws, "PRV " + pws, "Pump Station " + pws, "Tank " + pws, "Valve " + pws, "Water Treatment Plant " + pws]
root = r"V:\WATER_FACILITY\WATER_FACILITY.gdb"
symRoot = r"V:\ArcGIS_Tools\pws_id_tool"

for i, file in enumerate(files):
    path = os.path.join(root, files[i])  # Create directory path for featureclasses
    symPath = os.path.join(symRoot, files[i] + ".lyr")  # Create directory path for .lyr files
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(path, layers[i], "PWS_ID" + " = '" + pws + "'")  # Make all the layers from "files" list
    arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(layers[i], symPath)  # Apply the symbologies from "symNames" list.
    featureCount = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(layers[i]).getOutput(0))
    arcpy.AddMessage(layers[i] + " count = " + str(featureCount))
    if featureCount > 0:
        newLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(layers[i])
        arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, newLayer, "TOP")
    else:
        arcpy.AddWarning("No " + layers[i] + " features for this PWS.")
```

The only parameter entered is ID number.  I would like to have the user select which features they want to add to the map by using GetPramaterAsText  with the 'Data Type' set as boolean.  That way they can check, or uncheck, the boxes based on what features they want added to their mxd.  I' m not quite sure how I would approach this with the for loop, if it can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following should work:

```
import arcpy

# Set variables
pws = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
files = ["SERVICE_AREA_COMBO", "BACTI", "...", "WTP"]  # list all names used for feature classes and .lyr files.
#<snip...>

for i, filename in enumerate(files): #Note: Don't use "file" as a variable name, you will override a python builtin.
    try:
        addlayer = arcpy.GetParameter(i+1) # Note: GetParameter not GetParameterAsText so we get a bool instead of a string
    except RuntimeError: #asked for a non-existent parameter
        break

    arcpy.AddMessage('%s,%s'%(addlayer, filename))
    if addlayer:
        path = os.path.join(root, filename)  # Create directory path for featureclasses
        #<snip...>
```

Just make sure you add the same number of parameters to the script tool properties :

[image]

Comment: That's it! I will give it a try.